# php exec wget can't download big file

Tags: php

php(ubuntu):
`exec('wget -o '.$local.' '.$url);`

The file is only downloaded to 345m.(The file to be downloaded is 2G+)
but when I just shell:

`wget -o /filepath/xxx.zip http://xxxx/xxx.zip`

It can be downloaded completely.
I looked for php.ini and did not find any restrictions on it.
The files to download are in the LAN. The speed 40+m/s. does not know if there is any relationship.

Comment: any reason you can't use PHP's native methods to request the data? And what happens when you get to 345? Any errors or anything?

Comment: I try use curl. it's same result(345m). when 345, just run next line code.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I would think your script is exceeding php's [`max_execution_time`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) configuration value, or perhaps [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

I'm sure PHP itself doesn't have any problems downloading files of that size, but you need to consider the time required to download 2GB of information over the network can be a pretty noticable delay

Try increasing your [`max_execution_time`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) value to something way higher (or, 0, to disable it all together, but that's probably not the best idea) and see if it works.

Comment: LAN. It takes only a few seconds.

Comment: and i had `set_time_limit(0);ignore_user_abort(true);`

Comment: Try the execution time value as well.

Comment: I don't think they're related.I think it's a configuration problem because it's fast enough in the LAN. But on this basis, I still have no idea.

Comment: The data end is apache, and the downloader is nginx. PHP 7.2.1

Comment: Unbelievable！ Save in different folders to limit the difference. Save in www/ folder is 90m, save in stroage/ folder is 345m, save /root/ folder 2G can also be fully saved.

Comment: If you look at the manual link above for max_execution_time, apache also has a time limit, maybe that needs to be inccreased

Comment: Not related. The key question is which folder is saved

Comment: I see no way whatsoever with any logically designed system that the folder in which you're saving a file changes how much data can be saved. Did you make sure you have enough space on the partition you're saving the file to?

Comment: It's a shame, and it's really a hard disk space. It's been a long time to forget it.